# Heroku db:push error

Tags: database, heroku

Everytime I attempt to `heroku db:push`, I get the following error:

```
Saving session to push_201207011424.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 503
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <style type="text/css">
        html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
        iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }
      </style>
    <title>Application Error</title></head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <iframe src="//s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html">
        <p>Application Error</p>
      </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have the exact same error. Heroku status says everything is fine. Not sure whats going on!

Comment: Just trying to push again now, will update with how it goes.

Comment: Hey @rctneil! Glad your app is working again :) You should post that info in an answer below and mark it as 'accepted' - this helps other Stack Overflow users see that your question has been answered (see also [the FAQ here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/189918)). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try followings:

```
heroku restart

heroku db:push --confirm <app-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following command in your console:

`heroku logs | tail`

Then your output looks similar to:

```
2016-04-20T10:56:17.509354+00:00 heroku[router]: 
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST [...]
```

The indicated error code gives you more insights and you can look it up here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes